# TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'csr_matrix' when using np.asarray

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I'm writing a spam email classifier to learn sklearn , but i'm having some issues with the bag of words.
I'm getting this error:

`File ".\classify.py", line 28, in 
    model.fit(X,y)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\sklearn\naive_bayes.py", line 579, in fit
    X, y = check_X_y(X, y, 'csr')
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 573, in check_X_y
    ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 433, in check_array
    array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'csr_matrix'`

The source code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.externals import joblib
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer

spam_emails = joblib.load("spam_emails.pkl")
ham_emails = joblib.load("ham_emails.pkl")

def transform(array):    
    vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
    vectorized = vectorizer.fit_transform(array)
    transformer = TfidfTransformer()
    transformed = transformer.fit_transform(vectorized)
    return transformed

spam_emails = np.asarray(transform(spam_emails))

ham_emails = np.asarray(transform(ham_emails))

X = np.array(spam_emails, ham_emails) # the x values


y = np.array([1,0]) # The 2 labels to try to predict; 1 means spam, 0 means not spam

model = MultinomialNB()

model.fit(X,y)

joblib.dump(model, "mnb_model.pkl")
```

The spam_emails.pkl and ham_emails.pkl files simply contain all the emails in an array.

Comment: One of the arguments in your function call is a sparse matrix, when it should be a number.

Comment: The error traceback indicates that the error occurs in the `model.fit` call, where it is checking the form and type of the inputs.  But I don't see how it even got that far.  The `X = np.array...` should have raised an error before that, complaining about the 2nd argument.  You need to check (and show us) the type, dtype, and shape of all arrays - starting with the `X` and `y` and possibly working backwards.

Comment: @hpaulj Here: https://pastebin.com/AgusehLS

Comment: So  the `np.asarray(transform...)` produces a scalar, `0d`, object dtype array.  My guess is that `transform` produces a sparse `csr` matrix.  That should not be wrapped in `asarray`.  It you want a dense array use its own `.toarray()` method.  But the `Model.fit` error indicates that it is ok with a sparse matrix input.

Comment: What you trying to do with `np.array(spam_emails, ham_emails) `?  As inidicated before that will produce an error, since `np.array` takes only one positional argument.  The 2nd is interpreted as `dtype`.  Are you trying to concatenate two sparse matrices?